# Extracting the boldest/largest text from image using opencv or pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I have been using pytesseract to get the text from image. It is working fine to extract all the texts from the image. However, I want the largest or the biggest text detected from the image. The aim is to get the product name or brand name from the product image.

I have checked google-vision API but it is a paid option. I am seeking for free option if any experts here have achieved it.

Below are some of my tries and codes so far:

```
def align_text(im):
  coords = np.column_stack(np.where(img_thresh > 0))
  angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]
  if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)
  else:
    angle = -angle
  h,w = img.shape
  center = (w // 2, h // 2)
  
  M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
  rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img_thresh, M, (w, h),
            flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
  return rotated
# align image text
img = align_text(img)
# display rotated and aligned image
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

array = []
for i in range(len(rows)):
  array.append(pytesseract.image_to_string(img[rows[i][0]:rows[i][-1],:],config=custom_config))
```

Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: use opencv's text *detection* and assess the size of a bounding box relative to the amount of text you can extract from it. that ought to tell you something about the font size.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for some insights. So do you mean I should check the area occupied by each of the text in the image? Also I am confused regarding the bounding box that you have mentioned. So do you also mean the image boundary by that?